# Magento inserting bullet points before item listing

Tags: html, magento

So I am trying to build a page within Magento and I want display a list of recently viewed items on the page using the widget function built into magento, called "Recently Viewed Products

But for some reason the final page adds a bullet point before the item listing

so I tried adding

```
<ul><li style="list-style-type: none;"><p>{{widget type="reports/product_widget_viewed" page_size="5" template="reports/widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml"}}</p></li></ul>
```

and I still get the bullet point before the item listing

Answer (score 0):

check if the CSS style of the list is not overridden with an **!important** declaration

Comment: Would you know how to check this in magento?

Comment: Well, if this is happening is not a magento thing but CSS related. For example in Chrome to see the CSS style applied to an element jus right-click on the list element on the web page and choose Inspect Element from the drop down menu. This will open a new window on which you can see the html elements on the left panel and the CSS applied to it on the right pannel. That is how you can check which style is applied to the element and where is defined.